# Cannot install NetworkManager (nmcli) on Amazon Linux 2023

Tags: yum, networkmanager, amazon-linux

Freshly installed ec2 Amazon Linux 2023 instance. Was trying to inspect machine's network devices and status.

However `nmcli` seems unable to be installed through `yum install`:

```
$ sudo yum install NetworkManager
Last metadata expiration check: 1:22:33 ago on Thu Jun 22 13:56:00 2023.
No match for argument: NetworkManager
Error: Unable to find a match: NetworkManager
```

I am new to linux and have done some research on internet but no luck so far. Any guidance /directions would be much appreciated!

Comment: A quick glance suggests that Amazon Linux doesn't provide NetworkManager. Your choices for network interface configuration appear to be `systemd-networkd` and the legacy `network-scripts` package.